# SQL: How to get Previous Date from a Table Without Using Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, sql-view

I have a table called Stocks which contains Date, StocksID and Price. The table contains data of several different market stocks price in 2018. I would like to create a view of the Stocks table which shows the date, StocksID, previous_price, price and change_in_price. Previous_price means the price of the same stock the day before. I'm having problem in getting the previous_price without using any built-in function.

I tried getting the previous_price by getting price from the previous date, but I don't know how to get the previous date.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Example Output:

```
Date       | StocksID  | prevprice | price | change 
-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+--------
2012-01-04 |     1     |      0.91 |  0.92 |   0.01
2012-01-05 |     1     |      0.92 |  0.91 |  -0.01 
2012-01-06 |     1     |      0.91 |  0.90 |  -0.01 
2012-01-09 |     1     |      0.90 |  0.89 |  -0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good use case for [Postgres window function `LAG()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-window.html), available since version 9.4:

```
SELECT 
    s.*, 
    LAG(price) OVER(PARTITION BY s.stocksID ORDER BY s.date) previous_price,
    price - LAG(price) OVER(ORDER BY s.date) change
FROM Stocks s
```

This will give you the difference with the previous price of the same `stocksID`, ordered by `date`. Please note that, depending on your data, this might not be the price of the previous day (if, for example, you have lags in the date series).

Comment: I took the "No functions" to mean this too, but if the OP only means user functions then you are correct.

Comment: @TomC: yes... I cannot imagine why the OP would not want to use Postgres built-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a self join and a not exists.

p1 is current, p2 is previous

```
select p1.*, p2.* 
from price p1
left join price p2 on p2.StocksID=p1.StocksID and p2.Date<p1.Date
    and not exists(
        select * from price p3 
        where p3.StocksID=p1.StocksID and p3.Date<p1.Date
        and p3.Date>p2.date
    )
```